# Audio does not work on page load in Angular application

Tags: angular

I'm trying to play audio in angular

```
<audio id="player" loop>
<source src='{{ Url}}'/>
</audio>
```

Same code when i place in html runs but when i place the code in angular component getting this error :

> DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the
> document first.

Script:

```
  start_audio()
    { 

 var button = <HTMLAudioElement> document.getElementById("playbtn");

      var audio = <HTMLAudioElement> document.getElementById("player");

      button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        if(audio.paused){
          audio.muted =false;
          audio.play();
          button.innerHTML = "Pause";
        } else {
          audio.muted =false;
          audio.pause();
          button.innerHTML = "Play";
        }
      });  
   button.click(); 
}
```

i have checked other solutions but nothing is working

Comment: Did you written your function in Oninit()? I think for simple solution we dont need to write btn click listener, we can just write if else content and call it in ngOninit() Or ngAfterViewInit(). I think this will help in auto load of audio.

Comment: @MuthulakshmiM I have tried but browser is blocking it